# How do I automatically add a POM dependency based on a Class name in an Eclipse java text editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

While I am coding a java class I would like to be able to easily find and update my POM.xml with the correct dependency based on a simple Class name, a package name, or fully qualified Class name.  I think this could be through a quick fix or an easy short-cutted dialog based on my cursor.  Does this kind of functionality exist? I see the following mentioned at https://maven.apache.org/ide.html but I don't see how to do it.

*Quick fixes in the Java editor for looking up required dependencies/jars by the class or package name*

Also, the m2e eclipse plugin documentation and help is really lacking.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I heard rumours that this feature was removed from m2e in Eclipse. It would be great to have a replacement, though.